# Tkinter lento luego horas de funcionamiento

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

Hola tengo un problema en una interfaz gráfica con Tkinter, la aplicación toma valores de un sensor, tiene una ventana secundaria donde se puede configurar hora y fecha, todo funciona muy bien pero luego de 2 o 3 horas de funcionamiento continuo abro la ventana secundaria y al momento de cerrarla la aplicación se pone muy pero muy lenta. Para cerrar la ventana secundaria uso: ventanaSecundaria.destroy().
Por favor su ayuda si alguien sabe que pasa

Comment: Buen día, sin ver nada de código lo único que podríamos hacer es desearte mucha suerte para que lo resuelvas pronto. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega parte del código que sea relevante para crear y eliminar la ventana secundaria. ¿Estás creando algún otro elemento, ya sea en `tkinter` o variables, clases, etc... al momento de crear o destruir la ventana? Es posible que tengas un [`memory leak`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-leak-in-python-requests/) en tu código.

Comment: Has añadido la etiqueta #hilos. Esto podría ser relevante. ¿Estarás creando hilos dentro de algún bucle y éstos no terminan y por tanto se van "acumulando"?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Como han dicho tus compañeros, el problema depende de como codificaste tu programa. Sin publicar algo que nos permita ver que puede estar pasando, lo mejor que vas a conseguir es intentos de adivinanza que pueden aportar poco. Lectura recomendada [Como crear un Ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)